# Relation doesn't exist even with schema specified

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I got an error when trying to do a request with JPA.

I have specified in my class entity, the schema where the table is :

```
@Data 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dwp_schema")
public class Corridor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_corridor;
    private Integer id_floor;
    private String orientation;

}
```

And when I am doing a specific request in my repository :

```
public interface CorridorRepository extends JpaRepository<Corridor, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select * from corridor c inner join floor f on f.id_floor=c.id_floor INNER JOIN building b on f.id_building = b.id_building WHERE b.building_name=?1 AND f.floor_number=?2" ,nativeQuery = true)
    List<Corridor> getCorridorsByFloor(String building_name, int floor);
}
```

I have the following error in Postgres :

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "corridor" does not exist`

Does someone have an idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your DB and Schema in the connection string:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname?currentSchema=dwp_schema
```

Putting schema name right in the entity declaration would be a bad idea anyway - your DBA should be able to decide on schema names.

Answer (score 0):

Try write schema name before table name:

```js
    @Query(value = "select * from dwp_schema.corridor c inner join floor f on f.id_floor=c.id_floor INNER JOIN building b on f.id_building = b.id_building WHERE b.building_name=?1 AND f.floor_number=?2" ,nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I did it and it works even if it is annoying to do so for each table that I have. Because we are working on two schema in the same project.